# Successful Logoff using Session c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms

I'm trying to implement a log off system on my project.
I've the following:

mypage.cs

```
 protected void imgBtnLogOff_click( object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e )
        {
            Session.Clear();
            Session.RemoveAll();
            Session.Abandon();
            Response.Redirect( "./Logout.aspx" );
        }
```

Logout.aspx

```
<h2>Thanks and come again!</h2>
        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbLogIn" Text=" click to log in!" OnClick="login_in"></asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
```

Logout.aspx.cs

```
protected void login_in( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {

             Response.Redirect( "mypage.aspx" );
        }
```

Thing is, since it has no session,every time I enter the page in the first time this prompts for user and pw input. But using this logout method it redirects successfully but with the old user, without asking for information.

Any thoughts of richer ideas?

Comment: I would strongly advise against using session as a form of login. Look up forms authentication or if you need stateless authentication look up oAuth and JWT tokens.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/301240

Answer (score 2):

An advice I got back then is to redirect the user to a 'logout' page in the code have - Session.RemoveAll();
and redirect to the login page.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, unfortunately the problem wasn't within my code